# How to define a new stochastic process which is function of another process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I need to define a new process from for example Wiener process like $U(t)=f(W(t))$, (for example $f(x)=1+x^2$ ) and then calculate the average like $\langle U(t)U(s)\rangle$. Is it possible?

Comment: yes for example simply raising the processes to powers does not work: WienerProcess[]^2

Comment: Comment not an answer, in the documentation pages for the forthcoming Wolfram Language release (and the version of M10 on Raspberry Pi) you can see there is such functionality coming - http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedProcess.html

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley, nice, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly an overkill for this case but quite general :

define a simple process which returns the variable you want

```
procU = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[DifferentialD]w[t],  1 + x[t]^2, 
           {x, 0}, {t, 0}, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]] ;
```

now you can use it as :

```
Mean[procU[t]]
(* 1 + t *)

CovarianceFunction[procU, s, t]
(* 2 Min[s, t]^2 *)
```